# How can I compute an index offset from a given multidimensional array index manually?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

My teacher has given me the following `C` example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
      int array[2][2][3]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
      printf("%d",array[1][0][2]);
      return 0;
}
```

alongside with the question: *Which number will be printed out?* 
Possible answers:

- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8

**8** seems to be the correct answer, but I don't understand the explanation from my teacher:

> array[1][0][2] means: *1*(2*3)+0*(3)+3=9* - the 9th element of array starting from zero, i.e. **8**.

Comment: *9th element of array starting from zero* is obviously wrong. The problem is so simple, the teacher making the mistake should be called out on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C are just a way to represent memory.

You have array with 2, 2 and 3 values, meaning:

2 "biggest" elements containing 2 "big" elements cantaining 3 elements each.

In memory it looks like this:

```
1st element in array: array[0][0][0]
2nd element in array: array[0][0][1]
3rd element in array: array[0][0][2]
4th element in array: array[0][1][0]
5th element in array: array[0][1][1]
6th element in array: array[0][1][2]
7th element in array: array[1][0][0]
8th element in array: array[1][0][1]
9th element in array: array[1][0][2]
10th element in array: array[1][1][0]
11th element in array: array[1][1][1]
12th element in array: array[1][1][2]
```

When you initialize your array, it will assing your values in order matching elements in order: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

If you want to print array[1][0][2], you are actually printing 9th element in array, which has assigned value 8.

Answer (score 4):

Your Math teacher should explain little easier first. For 1D array

```
int 1d_arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

`1d_arr[2]` is equivalent to `*(1d_arr + 2)`, i.e. fetch the element of array `1d_arr` which is `2 * sizeof(1d_arr[2])` = `8` bytes far from the base address or `8/4`<sup>th</sup> = 2<sup>nd</sup> element, which is `3`. Note that base address is `1d_arr` itself (array to pointer conversion).

For 2D array

```
int 2d_arr[2][3] = { {0,1,2}
                     {3,4,5}
                   };
```

`2d_arr[0][2]` is equivalent to `*(*(2d_arr + 0) + 2)`, i.e. fetch the element of array `2d_arr` which is `0*sizeof(2d_arr[0]) + 2*sizeof(2d_arr[0][2])` = `8` bytes far from the base address or `0/4 + 8/4`<sup>th</sup> = 2<sup>nd</sup> element of array `2d_arr[0]`, which is `2`.

For 3d array

```
int 3d_arr[2][2][3] = { {0,1,2}, {3,4,5}
                        {6,7,8}, {9,10,11}
                      };
```

`3d_arr[1][0][2]` is equivalent to `*(*(*(3d_arr + 1) + 0) + 2)`, i.e. fetch the element of array `3d_arr` which is `1*sizeof(3d_arr[1]) + 0*sizeof(3d_arr[1][0]) + 2*sizeof(3d_arr[1][0][2])` = `1*(2*3*4) + 0*(3*4) + 2*4` = `32` bytes far from the base address or `24/4 + 0/4 + 8/4` = `6 + 0 + 2` = 2<sup>nd</sup> element of 0<sup>th</sup> element (an array) of array `3d_arr[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

*array[1][0][2] means 1*(2*3)+0*(3)+3=9th element of array starting from zero i.e. 8.*

is wrong, because element at [1][0][2] is not the 9th element starting from zero, but is in fact the 8th element starting from zero, and at the same time, the 9th element starting from 1.

A correct statement should therefore be either:

*array[1][0][2] means 1*(2*3)+0*(3)+2=8th element of array starting from zero.*

or(adding +1 to convert form indexing to numbering):

*array[1][0][2] means 1*(2*3)+0*(3)+2+1=9th element of array starting from one.*

Answer (score 2):

Here is the maths and output shows how dimensions give the results:
First 1 Second 0 Third 2 Num 8

```
Number[FirstDim][SecondDim][ThirdDim] = FirstDim *(Length of Second Dim -1) * (Length of third dim -1) +
SecondDim   *(Length of third dim -1) + ThirdDim
```

Here is the formula:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define FIRST 2
#define SECOND 2
#define THIRD 3
int main(){
  int i, j ,k;
  int array[FIRST][SECOND][THIRD]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
  for (i = 0 ; i < FIRST; i++) {
      for (j = 0 ; j < SECOND; j++) {
          for (k = 0 ; k < THIRD; k++) {
               printf("First %d Second %d Third %d Num %d", i, j, k, array[i][j][k]);
               printf("\n");
          }
          printf("First %d Second %d Third %d \n", i, j, k);
      }
      printf("First %d Second %d Third %d \n", i, j, k);
  }
  printf("%d",array[1][0][2]);

  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
First 0 Second 0 Third 0 Num 0
First 0 Second 0 Third 1 Num 1
First 0 Second 0 Third 2 Num 2

First 0 Second 1 Third 0 Num 3
First 0 Second 1 Third 1 Num 4
First 0 Second 1 Third 2 Num 5

First 1 Second 0 Third 0 Num 6
First 1 Second 0 Third 1 Num 7
First 1 Second 0 Third 2 Num 8

First 1 Second 1 Third 0 Num 9
First 1 Second 1 Third 1 Num 10
First 1 Second 1 Third 2 Num 11
```

Answer (score 1):

int array[2][2][3]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};

```
Consider 3D Array as an "array of 2D Array",like there are 2 * (2 X 3 array)
```

> Index View of an array

```
 0  -> 0  1  2
       3  4  5 

 1  -> 6  7  8
       9  10 11

Real Value in indexes are :

 as per indexing table
 first value will fall in 1 array of 2D array 
(in first row and first column array[0][0][0]) 

and second in 1 array of 2D array 
(in first row and second column array[0][0][1]) and so on...
```